# Clarification of what is meant by loop in $S^{1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am a little confused about what is meant by a loop in $S^{1}$. For example, let $f_{1}(t)= e^{2\pi it}$ defined on the interval $A= [0, 1/2]$ and $f_2 (t)=e^{2\pi i(1-t)}$  on the interval $B= [1/2, 1]$ then by the gluing lemma the path $\alpha (t)$ is $f_1(t)$ on $A$ and $f_2(t)$ on $B$ is continuous and $\alpha(0)=\alpha (1)$. But we don't have to stop there we can define a family of paths in $S^1$ such that don't traverse the whole circle $S^1$. How is this handled in the calculation of the fundamental group.

Answer (score 1):

Loops do not have to be surjective (and, typically, they are not). In the context of the fundamental groups $\pi_1(X,x)$, one considers **based loops,** which are maps $c: [0,1]\to X$ such that $c(0)=c(1)=x$, where $x$ is the base-point.

Comment: I understand that part. What I am not understanding is the set of all non-surjective loops have to be in the homotopy class of surjective loops because the fundamental group of the circle is $Z$. But can't we take any non-surjective loop and continuously deform it to a point in $S^{1}$?

Comment: @user11937: Yes, every non-surjective loop in $S^1$ is null-homotopic. Your other sentence "the set of all non-surjective loops have to be in the homotopy class of surjective loops because the fundamental group of the circle is " I do not understand. Are you asking if every non-surjective loop is homotopic to a surjective one? That would be true. But your questions should be clarified in the post, not in comments.